# Google Drive API: Export csv file data based on its text/csv id

Tags: python, csv, google-drive-api

I would like to export the data of a csv file contained in a google drive folder based on its Id.
If I know its Google Spreadsheet Id I can do it as follow:

```
request = service.files().export_media(fileId='idididididididididid', mimeType='text/csv').execute()
```

However I wanted to make this process automatic by looping over the csv of a folder - and by getting their id thanks to the following sample of code:

```
sn_folder_content = self.service.files().list(q='"'+sn_folder.get('id')+'"'+" in parents").execute()
sn_folder_name = sn_folder.get('name')
folder_files = sn_folder_content.get('files')
for file in folder_files:
     mime_type = file.get('mimeType')
     if mime_type == 'text/csv':                           
        id_ = file.get('id')
        self.service.files().export_media(fileId=id_, mimeType='text/csv').execute()
```

Which basically gets a list of all the files. if a file is of type Csv-s, I export its content. However this will throw an exception: "Export only supports Google Docs."
And unless I grab the google doc id manually (by double clicking on my csv in my drive, to then click on 'open with google spreadsheet') I wont be able to export them automatically. How am I supposed to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to download CSV files from your Google Drive using google-api-python-client with python.
- You have already been able to get the files using Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- You can retrieve only CSV files in the specific folder using the search query.

  - In your case, the search query is `"'"+sn_folder.get("id")+"'"+" in parents and mimeType='text/csv'"`.
  - By this, only CSV files can be retrieved from the specific folder.
- When the files except for Google Docs are downloaded, please use the method of `get_media` instead of `export_media`.

#### Modified script 1:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

In this modification, the following modules are used.

```
import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
```

The modified script is as follows.

```
sn_folder_content = self.service.files().list(
    q="'"+sn_folder.get("id")+"'"+" in parents and mimeType='text/csv'").execute()
# sn_folder_name = sn_folder.get('name')  # <--- It seems that this is not used.
folder_files = sn_folder_content.get('files')
for file in folder_files:
    print(file['name'])
    id_ = file.get('id')
    request = self.service.files().get_media(fileId=id_)
    fh = io.FileIO(file['name'], mode='wb')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print('Download %d%%.' % int(status.progress() * 100))
```

#### Modified script 2:

If you want to download Google Spreadsheet as the CSV file by converting, you can use the method of `export_media`. In this case, the modified script is as follows.

```
sn_folder_content = self.service.files().list(
    q="'"+sn_folder.get("id")+"'"+" in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'").execute()
# sn_folder_name = sn_folder.get('name')  # <--- It seems that this is not used.
folder_files = sn_folder_content.get('files')
for file in folder_files:
    print(file['name'])
    id_ = file.get('id')
    request = self.service.files().export_media(fileId=id_, mimeType='text/csv')
    fh = io.FileIO(file['name'] + '.csv', mode='wb')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print('Download %d%%.' % int(status.progress() * 100))
```

#### Reference:

- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.